# ActionScript - Formatting Zero With NumberFormatter?

Tags: actionscript-3, format, number-formatting, zero

i've assigned properties to a NumberFormatter object so that formatted values contain a leading zero, trailing zeros and a 2 decimal places.

the formatting works unless the number being formatted is 0.  how can i format a 0 with the set properties so that 0 becomes 0.00?

```
var numFormat:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter(LocaleID.DEFAULT);
numFormat.leadingZero = true;
numFormat.trailingZeros = true;
numFormat.fractionalDigits = 2;

trace(numFormat.formatNumber(46));      //46.00
trace(numFormat.formatNumber(0.556849));  //0.56
trace(numFormat.formatNumber(0));        //0
```

---

**[EDIT]**
i've remedied this problem by manually appending the locale decimal separator with the desired number of fractionalDigits if the formatted number is 0:

```
if (myFormattedNumber.text == "0" && numFormat.fractionalDigits)
   {
   myFormattedNumber.appendText(numFormat.decimalSeparator);

   for (var i:uint = 0; i < numFormat.fractionalDigits; i++)
       myFormattedNumber.appendText("0");
   }
```

i'm still very interested in knowing if this is a bug or a feature, but it seems like a oversight to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not sexy, but this was similar to what I used when I ran into a similar issue:

```
function numberFormat(number:*, maxDecimals:int = 2, forceDecimals:Boolean = false, siStyle:Boolean = true):String 
{
    var i:int = 0, inc:Number = Math.pow(10, maxDecimals), str:String = String(Math.round(inc * Number(number))/inc);
    var hasSep:Boolean = str.indexOf(".") == -1, sep:int = hasSep ? str.length : str.indexOf(".");
    var ret:String = (hasSep && !forceDecimals ? "" : (siStyle ? "," : ".")) + str.substr(sep+1);
    if (forceDecimals) for (var j:int = 0; j <= maxDecimals - (str.length - (hasSep ? sep-1 : sep)); j++) ret += "0";
    while (i + 3 < (str.substr(0, 1) == "-" ? sep-1 : sep)) ret = (siStyle ? "." : ",") + str.substr(sep - (i += 3), 3) + ret;
    return str.substr(0, sep - i) + ret;
}


trace("zero: " + numberFormat(0, 2, true, false))
```

[Full article here](http://flassari.is/2009/08/number-format-thousand-separator-in-as3/)

Comment: that code is terrifying.  lol.  it might be just as well to simply append ".00" on the returned string if it's zero.  it seems like this is bug in the NumberFormatter class.  formatNumber(), formatInt() and formatUint() all return "0" without desired format if the value passed to the formatter is 0.

Comment: Haha yeah, definitely not sexy.  It was something used for currency formatting, especially non-US.

Comment: Appending '.00' doesn't always do what you want if you change some of the settings.  Also, 0 returns 0.00 in Flash Player 11, so maybe you don't have to do anything.

Comment: what potential pitfall is there in if(numberString.text == "0")numberString.appendText(".00"); ?  also, can you explain more about Flash Player 11?  any links?

Answer (score 1):

How about `Number(value).toFixed(2)` ?

Comment: using NumberFormatter isn't trivial.  numbers are formatted for specific locales.  for example, in North America the number 5000 using a NumberFormatter with the properties listed above is converted to "5,000.00", whereas in Europe it might be "5.000,00" (notice the separators).